# Running a-frame with 360 photo embed on php code

Tags: php, aframe

I'm having some difficulties on loading a simple 360 photo '`embed`' within my `php script`.

There is no apparent error since a-frame planes and sky environment (even with ) work without any trouble.

> All `a-frame` required scripts load without problem but what is
>   **IMAGE or 360 PHOTOS** simply does not display anything.

This lines does not show anything:

```
<img id="main" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://digitalands.net/rolling-actions/Mansion/images/Library_1stFloor.jpg">
<img id="goA-thumb" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://digitalands.net/rolling-actions/assets/icons/door.jpg">
```

Yet, they work completely alright if running on a html page.

no errors. yet, the images does not show up.

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you've used to try and embed this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figure it out myself, surely inspired by your gifted ability to solve :)

The problem was just because the 360 degrees images were being loaded from other domain.
So, as a solution, all images must be hosted from the same domain where the php script is assisted by a-frame code lines.

So, now it's working fine :)